# How to solve $-1\leq \tan{x} \leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

How to solve $-1\leq \tan{x} \leq 1$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Does $\tan x$ exist at $\frac {n\pi} {2}$ for any integer $n$? What will happen to $\tan x$ if $x \to \frac {\pi} {2}$ and $x \to - \frac {\pi} {2}$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\implies\tan^2x\le1$$

$$\implies\cos2x=\dfrac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}\ge0$$

$$2n\pi-\dfrac\pi2\le2x\le2n\pi+\dfrac\pi2$$ where $n$ is any integer

Answer (score 2):

Solve on $[ -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$:
$$
-1\leq \tan x \leq 1 \Rightarrow x\in [-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}]
$$

Then take that modulo $\pi$ and you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by firstly looking at the graph of$ tan(x)$ in one period (preferably $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$).

We know that $tan(\pm\frac{\pi}{4})=\pm1$, therefore the solution set of the problem in the selected domain is $-\frac{\pi}{4} \leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{4}.$

And due to periodicity, add or subtract $n\pi $from the above interval gives the answer. That is 
$\{x\in \mathbb{R}| -\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi, n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$